# Why my samba printer is not visible (after boot) until i restart smb?

Tags: samba, ubuntu-9.10, printing, ubuntu-11.04

I've an old hp1100 and ubuntu 9.10 and now upgraded to lucid prerelease. I can't see my printer on network (using smb://mycomputer on nautilus or \mycomputr from xp). 
As long as i will not restart smbd (on lucid: sudo restart smbd) my printer is not visible as network share. All file shares are always visible. My printer is visible and working after smbd restart

Any clue what might cause this ?

**EDITED !SOLUTION!**

Easiest way to workaround this (at least in ubuntu 11.04 where this issue is still not solved) is to edit upstart smbd file located at:

```
/etc/init/smbd.conf
```

and replace line:

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up)
```

with:

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up and started cups)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely is that samba is coming up before cups, I suggest you report a bug to [launchpad](http://launchpad.net/).

Comment: seems bug is already filled at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/494141
anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem this morning (Ubuntu 11.04 - You would think they would fix this by now...).  I determined the problem after some Googling.  Yes, Samba is starting before CUPS, which causes Samba to not display the printers until you manually do 'sudo reload smbd'.

I modified **/etc/init/cups.conf**, not /etc/init/smbd.conf (basically adding "**or starting smbd**" to the end of the line)

```
start on (filesystem
    and (started dbus or runlevel [2345])
    and stopped udevtrigger) or starting smbd
```

I like this solution because it works for people with only CUPS installed or people with only Samba installed (I think).  Hope this helps someone out there...

Answer (score 1):

Better is not to tinker with the installed upstart files, but to add to /etc/rc.local

```
service cups restart 
service smbd restart
```

But you would indeed think they would have fixed this by now -- but no, I installed Xubuntu for a neighbour last night and the same thing happened. It's nearly as bad as the old error of starting network-dependent services on a laptop (where there might not be a connection at any given time) and then having a 10-minute timeout...